# Example use case of "carriage return"

Tags: return

I have recently encountered the concept of carriage return, but I couldn't think of a good test case where I would need it.

As a beginner, I am trying to help this concept set in my memory.  Any examples are appreciated!

Ayush

Comment: [Carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) on Wikipedia.  Read the Typewriter section.

Comment: "Carriage return" came from typewriter - mechanical device with mechanical typing carriage. When you want to start typing from a *new line*, you should perform *two* actions: move ("Carriage Return") cariage to the leftmost position and then roll paper forward ("Line Feed").